# Meaning of 别 in 别开生面?

Tags: meaning, characters, meaning-in-context, idioms, chengyu

I am aware of the fact that 别 usually means "don't", but what about :/ the expression 别开生面​。 Here, doors it mean "another"? What exactly does it mean in this context?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

别开生面 usually means to start something new, or to do something new

别 is used as 另外 (something else), or 别处 (another place, elsewhere)
开 is used as 开辟，开创 (invent/open up/start)
生面 is for 新的面目 (a new face/ a new appearance)

In context, it means to start another style, a new style, or start something new.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

别开生面 is actually an idiom which means "to break a new path" or "break fresh ground". In this case, 别 is just part of the idiom.

Answer (score 1):

> http://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%88%AB%E5%BC%80%E7%94%9F%E9%9D%A2/787396
>
> 别开生面: open up a fresh outlook

Yes, in 别开生面, 别 means "other / different" (as in "other way" or "different way")

别 (differently)

开 (open up)

生 (new )

面 (outlook)